# Redmine UI discrepancy

Tags: redmine, trac, issue-tracking

I am choosing between [Trac](https://trac.edgewall.org) and [Redmine](https://www.redmine.org). Leaving dogma out (they use Python and Ruby, resp.) I'm test-driving both to choose based on the usability of the UI.

At the outset I'm seeing a discrepancy between a [demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jDEpIL-OcUw) of Redmine

[image: Redmine demo]
and the view that I get when I install Redmine and launch the server locally.

[image: running Redmine locally]
Where is the difference coming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first screenshot above is from Planio, a hosted Redmine service. Some time ago, they've rolled out a custom, more modern design for their customers.

At the time, Planio published [a blog article](https://plan.io/blog/the-challenge-of-redesigning-redmine/) about the design goals and the process.

Answer (score 0):

They used a theme.
You can buy it here : https://bestredminetheme.com/boostmine/

Comment: Cool. Complete with a list of those who purchased the theme recently. Privacy be damned.